# Keep rows if difference between two values in column 2 exceeds certain amount; do this for each category given in column 1

Tags: subset, bioinformatics, difference

I want to subsample a file by keeping as many entries as possible whose difference in values in column 2 are at least 500 units, for each name in column 1.  The full file is ~200,000 lines long, sorted by column 1 then column 2, tab-separated, and looks something like this:

```
name1   107
name1   110
name1   472
name1   509
name1   599
name1   679
name1   710
name2   36
name2   179
name2   391
name2   696
name2   1427
name2   1583
name2   1722
name2   2090
name2   2136
name2   2235
name3   687
name3   933
name4   43
name4   207
name4   384
name4   439
name4   447
name4   603
name4   774
name4   802
name4   876
name4   988
```

I would like an output that looks like this:

```
name1   107
name1   679
name2   36
name2   696
name2   1427
name2   2090
name3   687
name4   43
name4   603
```

I think one way to do it is to keep the first entry for each name and then keep the next entry for that name that is at least 500 units larger, and then the next entry that is at least 500 larger than that, etc.  Then, repeat for each name.  It would also be fine if it was in reverse starting with the last entry for each name, or it would be fine if it started elsewhere as long as it maximized the number of entries retained for each name that are greater 500 units apart.

However, I have no idea how to code this, as I am a novice!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What did you tried? Do you realize that this is almost nothing to do with bioinformatics? It is just about storing values with a difference of 500 or more? Did you tried a for loop to iterate over the file and store a dictionary of type name1:[#1, #2,...] And then select in the way you want?

Comment: Hi Llopis, Thank you for your reply.  I have not tried anything other than playing around in Excel because I have very limited experience beyond the most basic commands.  How do you suggest I implement the loop you mentioned?  I tagged my question as bioinformatics because the numbers are base pair positions along contigs ("names")... I thought someone in the bioinformatics community might have already tried to do what I am asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose to do it in Python, which is turning into the lingua franca of bioinformatics.

(Learn enough Python for your biology needs here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

Copy the following into a file and run it with `python script_name.py input_textfile.txt`

(If you do not know enough python to do that chapters 0 and 1 in the book referred to above will help you)

```
import sys

name_column = 0
number_column = 1
last_name = "dummy variable"
last_number = -1
min_difference = 500

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:

        name = line.split()[name_column]
        number = int(line.split()[number_column])

        if name != last_name:
            print(line.strip())
            last_number = number
            last_name = name
            continue

        if (number-last_number) >= min_difference:
            print(line.strip())
            last_number = number
```

Output using data above:

```
name1   107
name1   679
name2   36
name2   696
name2   1427
name2   2090
name3   687
name4   43
name4   603
```

If you want the output in a file, use `python script_name.py input_textfile.txt > output_file`

Comment: +1 for "Python, which is turning into the lingua franca of bioinformatics." I like to hear that but I found still many programs in C when speed is required